# Dynamically adding words to a context in REBOL

Tags: rebol, rebol2

Imagine the following REBOL code:

```
foo: context [bar: 3]
```

I now have a context `foo` in which `'bar` is defined. How can I dynamically inject a new word into this context? Is it possible?

I've tried:

```
set/any in foo 'baz 3
```

But that doesn't work because the expression `in foo 'baz` fails because there is no word `'baz` defined in the `foo` context.

I should add that I realize one way to do this is as follows:

```
foo-prototype: [bar: 3]
foo: context foo-prototype
foo: context head append foo-prototype [baz: 3]
```

But what if you don't have access to `foo`'s prototype block?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve the same by using the existing object as a prototype to create a new object.

```
>> foo: make object! [bar: 3]
>> foo: make foo [baz: 3]
>> probe foo
make object! [
    bar: 3
    baz: 3
]
```

Comment: This is one of the fundamental aspects of REBOL, but at the time I asked this question, I wasn't aware you could do this.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to work around the fact that in REBOL/2 it's just not posssible to extend object contexts.

Probably you can just use BLOCK!s instead of OBJECT!s:

```
>> blobject: [foo 1]
== [foo 1]
>> blobject/bar
** Script Error: Invalid path value: bar
** Near: blobject/bar
>> append blobject [bar 2]
== [foo 1 bar 2]
>> blobject/bar: 3
== 3
```

You can even make 'self working by just appending the object itself:

```
>> insert blobject reduce ['self blobject]
== [[...] foo 1 bar 2]
>> same? blobject blobject/self
== true
```

But as you've asked for extending *OBJECT!s*, you may go for Peter W A Wood's solution to simply clone the object. Just keep in mind that with this approach the resulting clone really is a different thing than the original object.

So, if some word has been set to hold the object prior to cloning/extending, after cloning the object that word will still hold the unextended object:

```
>> remember: object: make object! [foo: 1]
>> object: make object [bar: 2]
>> same? remember object
== false
>> probe remember
make object! [
   foo: 1
]
```

In case it's essential for you to keep "references" to the object intact, you might want to wrap the object you need to extend in an outer object as in

```
>> remember: object: make object! [access: make object! [foo: 1]]
>> object/access: make object/access [bar: 2]
>> same? remember object
== true
```

You can then safley extend the object while keeping, given you only store references to the container.

REBOL/3, btw, will allow adding words to OBJECT!s.

Comment: Very informative answer! I've learned a TON about REBOL since I posted this question.

Answer (score 1):

Said in REBOL/Core User Guide:
"Many blocks contain other blocks and strings.  When such a block is copied, its 
sub-series are not copied.  The sub-series are referred to directly and are the same 
series data as the original block."

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't this relate to `object!`s instead of `blocks!`s?